# How to change a static IP to a dynamic or at least change it?

Tags: ip-address, ip, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have a static IP address and I want to change it or convert it into a dynamic IP address. How would I do this? I'm using a Linksys router and running Mac OS X.

Comment: Your internal or external IP address? I'd say you mean internal, but just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If the IP address you're talking about is your address given by your ISP, then there isn't anything you can really do there. Conceivably, you could access the internet through some service that will 'give' you a dynamic IP - essentially a proxy - but your static IP still remains.

If the IP address you're referring to is internal, and somehow the router will only deal with your OS X installation when you use a static IP, but you *really* want a dynamic IP locally just so you could ping it, change it, and then ping something different... That can't be what you mean.

I assume you mean your external IP address so you could get around a site ban or filesharing website daily limit? I'm not sure this is the place I can condone it, but suffice it to say if you've got a static IP from your ISP, you can't make it dynamic from your end. You could call them and ask for a dynamic IP - some ISPs are happy to provide.

If you can give a bit of background on why you'd like a dynamic IP, I'm sure we'd be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about your INTERNAL IP which start with 192.x.x.x or 172.x.x.x
or 10.x.x.x usually linksys use 192.168.1.1 as gateway and range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.100

Check list:

Linksys:
Setup tab :
If you have static from ISP, call to your Internet provider and request change your IP to Dynamic.

Mac:
Apple-System Preferences-Network
Choice your active currenbt adapter on the left pannel (Ethernet or WiFi) with green dot and status connected.
Advanced tab-TCP/IP tab
Change your static IP status to DHCP and click DHCP release

Answer (score -1):

The problem is having two computers having the same address and when  both are  connected  to the internet, one is refused entry and one gets the message that someone else is trying to get into the system. If the computers had different IP addresses I am told the problem would disappear

Comment: How does this answer OP question?